# Can Someone help me to solve this issue in Siddhi Stream Processor?

Tags: mysql, siddhi

```
[2020-05-06_16-31-42_744] ERROR {com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool} - HikariPool-32 - Exception during pool initialization. 
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at io.siddhi.extension.store.rdbms.RDBMSEventTable.initializeDatasource(RDBMSEventTable.java:1362)
    at io.siddhi.extension.store.rdbms.RDBMSEventTable.connect(RDBMSEventTable.java:1092)
    at io.siddhi.core.table.record.AbstractQueryableRecordTable.connectAndLoadCache(AbstractQueryableRecordTable.java:206)
    at io.siddhi.core.table.Table.connectWithRetry(Table.java:406)
    at io.siddhi.core.SiddhiAppRuntimeImpl.startWithoutSources(SiddhiAppRuntimeImpl.java:455)
    at io.siddhi.core.SiddhiAppRuntimeImpl.start(SiddhiAppRuntimeImpl.java:424)
    at io.siddhi.distribution.editor.core.internal.DebugRuntime.start(DebugRuntime.java:93)
    at io.siddhi.distribution.editor.core.internal.DebugProcessorService.start(DebugProcessorService.java:42)
    at io.siddhi.distribution.editor.core.internal.EditorMicroservice.start(EditorMicroservice.java:761)
    at io.siddhi.distribution.editor.core.internal.EditorMicroservice.startWithVariables(EditorMicroservice.java:781)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.router.HttpMethodInfo.invokeResource(HttpMethodInfo.java:187)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.router.HttpMethodInfo.invoke(HttpMethodInfo.java:143)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener.dispatchMethod(MSF4JHttpConnectorListener.java:218)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener.lambda$onMessage$58(MSF4JHttpConnectorListener.java:129)


    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2120)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2143)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1310)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:967)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    ... 30 more



[2020-05-06_16-31-42_749] ERROR {io.siddhi.core.table.Table} - Error on 'Assignment_02_01'. Failed to initialize pool: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support. . Error while connecting to Table 'table1'. (Encoded) 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:597)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:576)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at io.siddhi.extension.store.rdbms.RDBMSEventTable.initializeDatasource(RDBMSEventTable.java:1362)
    at io.siddhi.extension.store.rdbms.RDBMSEventTable.connect(RDBMSEventTable.java:1092)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please include your code, and a description of your environment? Please review the SO [guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and have a quick read of [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) which contains a checklist of actions to take before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Cause was

> The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents
>   more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC
>   driver

[In jdbcURL string](https://vladmihalcea.com/jdbc-driver-connection-url-strings/)

update it to

```
?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

put above line to after your db name check below example

```
databaseName=yourDbNameThenput?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```